# _frontendCSRF cookie appears to be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, yii2

I got this testing issue from my testing company that `_frontendCSRF` cookie can cause sql injection. They provide it for `login` page. My application is build over `yii2`. Here is the details information.

> The _frontendCSRF cookie appears to be vulnerable to SQL injection
>   attacks. The payload ')and%20benchmark(20000000%2csha1(1))--%20 was
>   submitted in the _frontendCSRF cookie. The application took 11004
>   milliseconds to respond to the request, compared with 1681
>   milliseconds for the original request, indicating that the injected
>   SQL command caused a time delay.

```
Cookie: PHPFRONTSESSID=62ca0ebed7ad7d7c5e15a8c267f77551; current_shop=2; site_url=http%3A%2F%2F52.6.251.159%2F%7Edemoecom%2Fbuyold%2Ffrontend%2Fweb; blog_url=http%3A%2F%2F52.6.251.159%2F%7Edemoecom%2Fbuyold%2Fblog; is_buyold_login=0; _language=ba7c0570c541af8890cb020f80553258ee37070af083c555286d73a4165020c5a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A9%3A%22_language%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A2%3A%22au%22%3B%7D; _frontendCSRF=ae5e122353d27ce1288157fc2b42e65dacf96d5fc4c5d0d7f883c19215138691a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A13%3A%22_frontendCSRF%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%22S8P_oYh_fNd-eODMV4NMrUqkebCWEKsL%22%3B%7D')and%20benchmark(20000000%2csha1(1))--%20; __atuvc=6%7C31; __atuvs=57a03a16ead33d80005
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 153
```

Right now my project is in beta mode so it is in `http`. What would be the solution for it?
Can i use `_frontendCSRF` in session or `https` will solve it ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a current version of Yii? I'd be surprised if this is a bug that hasn't been addressed somehow.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds pretty alarming but looking at the actual code from the current Yii 2.0.9 framework I don't see any SQL being used in the validation process: [yii2/web/Request.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/Request.php)

Now I'm not a a security expert... you might want to

1. get a more technically detailed report from your testing company so the test can be reproduced on a clean install of yii2
2. file a security issue: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues